# I can't connect to pgAdmin, my password is right but telling to me some issue

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

connection failed: :1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections? connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Comment: Is the server running on your own machine? Or are you trying to connect to a remote server?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The server is running on my own computer. I am trying to connect pgadmin4 to visual code so I can run to localhost. I’m sorry my english is not good. Appreciated to your help

Comment: @Jackie Are you sure Postgres server is running on your machine? You'll need to install both pgAdmin and [Postgres server](https://www.postgresql.org/download/). And are you sure the server started correctly (can you see it in your task manager)? What OS are you running?

Comment: I’m using macOS Monterey 12.7.1 i downloaded Postgres through the installer. Thank you for you patience answering my question